# Set 'enctype' form attribute in moodle form?

Tags: moodle

I am creating a form in moodle. I require `multipart/form-data` in enctype attributes to work with files. But I don't know where the attribute should be set. And how to set it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Files API with the Forms API for uploading files.

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Using_the_File_API_in_Moodle_forms

UPDATE: Haven't tested this but its a cut down version of some existing code I have

In your edit.php file have something like this:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/edit_form.php');

$id = optional_param('id', null, PARAM_INT);

if ($id) {
    // Existing record
    $record = $DB->get_record('mytablename');
} else {
    // New record
    $record = new stdClass();
    $record->id = null;
    $record->myfield = '';
    ...
}

// Prepare the files.
$fileoptions = array(
    'maxbytes' => get_max_upload_file_size(),
    'maxfiles' => '1', // Change this to how many files can be uploaded.
    'subdirs' => 0, // No sub directories.
    'context' => $context
);
$record = file_prepare_standard_filemanager($record, 'myfiles',
        $fileoptions, $context, 'mypluginname', 'myfiles', $record->id);

$mform = new edit_form(null, array('fileoptions' => $fileoptions));

if ($formdata = $mform->get_data()) {
    // Form has been submitted.
    if (empty($formdata->id)) {
        // New record so create it.
        $recordid = $DB->insert_record('mytablename', $formdata);
        $record = $DB->get_record('mytablename', array('id' => $recordid));
    } else {
        // Update it.
        $DB->update_record('mytablename', $formdata);
        $record = $DB->get_record('mytablename', array('id' => $id));
    }
    // Save the files.
    $formdata = file_postupdate_standard_filemanager($formdata, 'myfiles',
            $fileoptions, $context, 'mypluginname', 'myfiles', $record->id);

} else {
    // Display the form.
    $mform->set_data($record);
    $mform->display();
}
```

And in your edit_form.php have something like this

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die;

require_once($CFG->libdir . '/formslib.php');

class edit_form extends moodleform {

    public function definition() {

        $fileoptions = $this->_customdata['fileoptions'];

        $mform =& $this->_form;

        $mform->addElement('hidden', 'id');
        $mform->setType('id', PARAM_INT);

        ...

        $mform->addElement('filemanager', 'myfiles_filemanager',
                get_string('myfiles', 'mypluginname'), null, $fileoptions);

        $this->add_action_buttons(false, get_string('submit'));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you
Mr. Russell
For your suggestion but
I had look and study FILES API and FORM API many times but I can't understand.

Comment: Okay, I'll write an example later today when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but did not see anything in the Moodle documentation. This works as of Moodle 3.11.

```
class my_form extends moodleform {

 ...
 $mform = $this->_form;
 ...

 $attr = $mform->getAttributes();
 $attr['enctype'] = "multipart/form-data";
 $mform->setAttributes($attr);
}
```